# hello, iam using mpdf to convert html to pdf, and the issue is showing a pdf inside the generated pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

iam using mpdf to convert html to pdf, and the problem is showing a pdf inside the generated pdf

i am going to show what iam doing :

```
<div class="landscape">

<a href="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>">Download PDF</a>

<a href="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>"><embed src="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>" width="500" height="375"></a>

<embed src="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>" width="500" height="375">


<div id="pdf">
<object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>" id="pdf_content">
                                <p>Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed.</p>
</object>
</div>  

<object data="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
alt : <a href="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>">test.pdf</a>
</object>



</div>
```

i have tried embed , object and the pdf its not opening inside the generated pdf

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running the HTML you are generating through a validator first to check for any syntax errors.  Fixing these errors might sort out the problems.  From looking at the code above it looks like you might have quite a few.